# How to avoid re-creating activity when fill screen mode changed in android 3.2?

Tags: android, zooming

In android 3.2, it adds a new compatibility zoom mode to give a new way to view fixed-sized apps on larger devices.

When switch fill screen mode(from zoom mode to stretch mode or from stretch mode to zoom mode), the activity will be re-created.

Is there any method to avoid re-creating activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this circumstance belongs to the category "Run Time Changes" - similar to the screen rotation.
Have a look here to see how to deal with that:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html